# Failed to download files from FTP server In Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin, inno-tools-downloader

I Couldn't download the files from FTP server using the Sherlock's inno downloader code.I provided the URL in this format:[ftp://username:password@www.mywebsite.com:8080/myfile.exe](ftp://username%3apassword@www.mywebsite.com:8080/myfile.exe), as specified in the help file. Please help me in this regard.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work with the InnoTools Downloader.

You need to switch to InnoDownloadPlugin: https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/ It's a drop-in replacement with better features: FTP, FTP-folder, HTTPS support.